# Time Out in Api rest Express Nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I want to put my api in time out. I tried to put it in a "global" way when I create the server but the answer only says that no data was returned, not a 504 error. I also have the option to place it for each route, I think the time out should go in the controller of my app .

```
function initialize() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const app = express();
    httpServer = http.createServer(app);
    app.use(morgan('combined'));
    app.use('/proyecto', router_proyecto);
    app.use('/tramitacion',router_tramitacion);
    httpServer.listen(webServerConfig.port, err => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
    //httpServer.timeout = 500;
      console.log('Servidor web escuchando en puerto:'+webServerConfig.port);
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

exaple of a route:

```
router_proyecto.route('/getProyecto/:proyid?')
    .get(proyecto.getProyecto);
```

Controller(Time out should go here):

```
async function getProyecto(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const context = {};
    context.proyid = parseInt(req.params.proyid, 10);
    const rows = await proyectos.getProyecto_BD(context);
    if (rows.length >0) {
      res.status(200).json(rows);
    } else {
      res.status(404).end();
    }
    } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
}
module.exports.getProyecto = getProyecto;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does "time out" mean to you? Because a a timeout is a [well defined term in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and your server should definitely not be using that. If you want your server to simply serve some content with a specific HTTP code, depending on some global flag, then you were on the right track except you need to write it as middleware.

```
let lock = Date.now();

function serveLockContent(req, res, next) {
  if (lock <= Date.now()) {
    return next();
  }

  res.status(503).write('Server unavailable');
}

...

app.use(serveLockContent);

...    

app.post('/lock/:seconds', verifyAuth, otherMiddlerware, (req, res) => {
  lock = Date.now() + (parseInt(req.params.howlong) || 0) * 1000;
  res.write('locked');
});
```